# How do I compare fields in a database query?

Tags: 8, database

Given the query fragment:

```
$query = $connection->select('mytable', 't');
$query->addField('t', 'myfield1', 'myfield1');
$query->addField('t', 'myfield2', 'myfield2');
```

I need to add a condition like this:

```
$query->condition('t.myfield1', 't.myfield2', '=');
```

But it doesn't seem to work. For comparison, I can use:

```
$query->condition('t.myfield1', 'banana', '=');
```

... and that works. But it seems comparing two fields to see if they match does not work? I can write this out in straight SQL code and properly query the database in a console, but can't duplicate in Drupal's database API.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use [`where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/function/ConditionInterface%3A%3Awhere/8.2.x), like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('mytable', 't')
  ->addField('t', 'myfield1', 'myfield1')
  ->addField('t', 'myfield2', 'myfield2')
  ->where('t.myfield1 = t.myfield2');
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I could not find that on the documentation - at least not where I looked. :-/